# Trouble shooting Material styles not loading on mat-button Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I created an app with `ng new` and added Material with `ng add @angular/material`. When I run `ng serve` I do not see to have the material style.css loaded despite having in my `angular.json`

```
"architect": {
  "build": {                                                         
    "options": {
      "styles": [                                                    
        "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",                                                                     
        "src/styles.scss"                                            
      ],                                                             
  ...
```

What else am I missing? When I look at the chrome dev console, I see it's loading

- `content_scripts.css`
- `frontend.css`
- `shadow.css`

And one css for the fonts (`fonts?family..`) and one for the icons `icon?family..`

---

I've also tried adding to my `styles.scss` the following,

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Which also resulted in no additional css files being brought in.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For me, I had created buttons that were unstyled. I actually copied the example from the docs on [menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview). I didn't realize that the buttons in the example needed more than just that which was documented in the API tab. They otherwise worked with just,

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

So when I ran that import in my app's `module.ts` and added it to my `imports` array it worked. As to why manually including the style with a `<link>` element didn't work,I was getting the following error when I tried that:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

As for the `@import` in `styles.scss`, it seems to be a NOP with Angular 7 if you have

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

If you also have it configured in your `angular.json`. Everything is working now without the `@import` statement anywhere.

- [Doc bug opened here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15230)

Comment: For me the line with `@import ... *.css` inside the component's scss file fixed the issue. That did it. Many thx.

Answer (score 7):

Please remove the css import from angular.json and put it into your styles.scss file.

So it will look like this.

> angular.json

```
"architect": { "build": { ... "styles": [ "src/styles.scss" ], ... },
```

> styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

If you have issue with upper one add the below lines to styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming'; // Plus imports for other components in your app. // Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only // have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app. // Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once! @include mat-core(); // Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss // (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker // hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/ $candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo); $candy-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400); // The warn palette is optional (defaults to red). $candy-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red); // Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes). $candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn); // Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app. // Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component // that you are using. @include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

I just paste it from docs.

Also you can add this to index.html by following code

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Let me know if its work or you need anything else.

Comment: I tried that too I added that note in the question except my import was `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; ` (with a tilde) I had the wrong import statement previously.

Comment: Remove ~ this before @angular, cause from angular 6 how you import was changed.

Comment: same thing, no joy.

Comment: Can you just remove @angular/material and add it again through ng add @angular/material .. and when there is question select theme used Custom there

Comment: that's what I did to get it in the first place.

Comment: Then just show me your styles.scss file in the question

Comment: It's in the question, that's literally all I have in it  -- I started with the Tilde (which is what the docs show) and removed it as per your suggestion and it changed nothing.

Comment: Just paste the code that inside styles.scss file in  your question. So I can figured it out.

Comment: It's in the question, that's literally all I have in it -- I started with the Tilde (which is what the docs show) and removed it as per your suggestion and it changed nothing. – Evan Carroll 3 mins ago    Edit    Delete

Comment: See i update the answer try it if its not working then I can make a stackblitz demo

Comment: Major oversight on my side, the MatButton I was using to generate the style worked fine because it was a just a `<button>` (duh!) adding that and it's all golden. I upvoted for your work you put into it. Thanks

Comment: For my issue, the solution was to manually add the import of the CSS file. For some reason, it wasn't automatically imported when I installed material in the app. Never happened to me before, that's why I wasn't checking in this direction... Anyway, the important thing is that I resolved the issue thanks to your answer here, and now can move on with the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the file `angular.json` is setup correctly, do check if your components attribute `color` setup properly, i.e.

```html
<mat-component color="primary">
```

Comment: This question is not closed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in Angular 12. I imported the MaterialModule in App Module, but that did not apply the colors. So I fixed it by including the following css file import in the styles.scss file of Angular project.
`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';`

So here's the complete solution:

`material.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';


@NgModule( {
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatDividerModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ]
} )

export class MaterialModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module'; // For Angular Material support
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout"; // For Angular Flex layout

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`styles.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

Hope the above solution helps someone.